# Elixir simple_one_for_one supervisor's start_child terminates with undefined handle_call/3

Tags: elixir, erlang-supervisor

I am trying to create a supervisor using gproc for process registry. The following code defines the supervisor:

```
defmodule QueueSupervisor do
    use Supervisor

    def start_link do
        GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, [], name: :model_queue)
    end

    def create_queue(name) do
        Supervisor.start_child(:model_queue, [name])
    end

    def init([]) do
        children = [
            worker(ModelQueueWriter, [])
        ]

        supervise(children, strategy: :simple_one_for_one)
    end

    def terminate(reason,_state) do
        Logger.info "terminating: #{inspect self}: #{inspect reason}"
        :ok
    end
end
```

The supervisor starts like a charm. However, when calling `create_queue(:some_name)`, I get an undefined function error:

```
function QueueSupervisor.handle_call({:start_child, [:some_name]}, {#PID<0.2278.0>, #Reference<0.0.3.3361>}, {{:simple_one_for_one, 3, 5}, [{ModelQueueWriter, {ModelQueueWriter, :start_link, []}, :permanent, 5000, :worker, [ModelQueueWriter]}]}
```

`ModelQueueWriter` is a simple genserver, using gproc for naming:

```
defmodule ModelQueueWriter do
    use GenServer

    def start_link(queue_name) do
        GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, [], name: via_tuple(queue_name))
    end

    defp via_tuple(queue_name) do
        {:via, :gproc, {:n, :l, {:model_queue, queue_name}}}
    end

    def init(_), do: %{:ok, []}
end
```

I am using elixir 1.4 and followed the doc for Supervisor, plus this [example](https://github.com/brianstorti/elixir-registry-example-chat-app).

What am I missing?

---

Upon request the full error message:

```
** (exit) exited in: GenServer.call(:model_queue, {:start_child, [:some_name]}, :infinity)
    ** (EXIT) an exception was raised:
        ** (UndefinedFunctionError) function QueueSupervisor.handle_call/3 is undefined or private
        (ecohesion_web) QueueSupervisor.handle_call({:start_child, [:model_queue]}, {#PID<0.2278.0>, #Reference<0.0.1.8826>}, {{:simple_one_for_one, 3, 5}, [{ModelQueueWriter, {ModelQueueWriter, :start_link, []}, :permanent, 5000, :worker, [ModelQueueWriter]}]})
        (stdlib) gen_server.erl:629: :gen_server.try_handle_call/4
        (stdlib) gen_server.erl:661: :gen_server.handle_msg/5
        (stdlib) proc_lib.erl:240: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
11:01:17.094 [error] GenServer :model_queue terminating
** (UndefinedFunctionError) function QueueSupervisor.handle_call/3 is undefined or private
(ecohesion_web) QueueSupervisor.handle_call({:start_child, [:model_queue]}, {#PID<0.2278.0>, #Reference<0.0.1.8826>}, {{:simple_one_for_one, 3, 5}, [{ModelQueueWriter, {ModelQueueWriter, :start_link, []}, :permanent, 5000, :worker, [ModelQueueWriter]}]})
(stdlib) gen_server.erl:629: :gen_server.try_handle_call/4
(stdlib) gen_server.erl:661: :gen_server.handle_msg/5
(stdlib) proc_lib.erl:240: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
Last message: {:start_child, [mode_queue]}
State: {{:simple_one_for_one, 3, 5}, [{ModelQueueWriter, {ModelQueueWriter, :start_link, []}, :permanent, 5000, :worker, [ModelQueueWriter]}]}
       (elixir) lib/gen_server.ex:737: GenServer.call/3
(ecohesion_web) lib/ecohesion_web/archive_writer/queue_supervisor.ex:28: QueueSupervisor.create_queue/1
```

Comment: Can you post the complete error message including the stacktrace?

Comment: I edited the post.

Comment: Typo in `QueueSupervisor.start_link`: `GenServer.start_link` should be `Supervisor.start_link`.

Comment: Oh wow. What a pity. That solved the problem actually, shame on me! Why does that even start the supervisor properly? If you create an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're starting a `GenServer` instead of `Supervisor` in `QueueSupervisor.start_link/0`. This should work:

```
defmodule QueueSupervisor do
  def start_link do
    Supervisor.start_link(__MODULE__, [], name: :model_queue)
  end
end
```

> Why does that even start the supervisor properly?

It starts a `GenServer`; it's just that the arguments you've used are compatible with both `Supervisor.start_link/3` and `GenServer.start_link/3`.